# Ember-cli-rails and Foundation Js modules

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember-cli

I am using `ember-cli-rails` gem. I installed `ember-cli-foundation-sass` as an `addon` for `ember`. Everything works fine but `Foundation Js module`. I made a layout just for `Ember` like this:

```
<!doctype html>
 <html dir="ltr" lang="<%= I18n.locale %>">
  <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>Ember</title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'frontend/frontend' %>
    <%= include_ember_script_tags :frontend %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  </head>
<body>
 <%= yield %>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried different settings, but none of them worked. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I solved the problem. I just forgot to put what it supposed to be put in `Brocfile.js`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. I just forgot to put what it supposed to be put in Brocfile.js